# iterate through a list and restart index_1 at 0 if list index is out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I am trying to make a program where I have a list `my_list_1 = [1,2,3,...]` and a second list `my_list_2 = [1,2,3,...] and len(my_list_1) < len(my_list_2). I want to iterate through the lists like this:

```
my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
result = []

for i in range(len(my_list_2)):
    result.append(my_list_1[i] + my_list_2[i])
    # i == 0: 1 + 5 = 6
    # i == 1: 2 + 6 = 8
    # i == 2: 3 + 7 = 10
    # i == 3: 1 + 8 = 9
    # i == 4: 2 + 9 = 11
    """ what I want to happen is when i > len(my_list_1), instead of giving a index out of range
        error, I want the loop to start at the beginning if the smaller list"""
```

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(my_list_2)):
    if i % (len(my_list_1) - 1) == 0 or i == 0:
        x = 0
    else:
        x+=1
   result.append(my_list_1[x] + my_list_2[i])
```

or

```
for i in range(len(my_list_2)):
   if x == (len(my_list_1) - 1) or i == 0:
       x = 0
   else:
       x += 1
   result.append(my_list_1[x] + my_list_2[i])
```

this works but I am looking for something a bit more elegant and possibibly even making a copy of `my_list_1` and extend it to the length of `my_list_2` so that it would look like this:

```
>>> my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
>>> my_list_2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
>>> extend_list(my_list_1, len(my_list_2))
[1,2,3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need modulo for the first index:

```
for i in range(len(my_list_2)):
    x = i % len(my_list_1)
    result.append(my_list_1[x] + my_list_2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.cycle` to create a cyclical list iterator, and use `zip` for the iterator and the other list.

```py
from itertools import cycle

my_list_1 = [1,2,3]
my_list_2 = [5,6,7,8,9]

# I use list comprehension here
result = [ a + b for a, b in zip(cycle(my_list_1), my_list_2) ]

print(result)
# [6, 8, 10, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use modulo in the indices

```
l = len(my_list_1)
for i in range(len(my_list_2)):
    result.append(my_list_1[i%l] + my_list_2[i])
```